# Calculating a percentage value based on a start and a end Timestamp

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to calculate the percentage value of how much time has been completed since a starting time.

To make things visualize better this is what I'm building. I already have the counter working counting down to the ending time but I want the percentage of time that has been completed because that is what will control the width of the green bar.

[image]

I'm using react.js but to break it down dateEnd and dateStart are both REST API values that look like this

"start_time": "2017-09-19 00:00:00"

"end_time": "2017-10-23 23:59:59"

So to recap I want the percentage of how much time has passed between these two values.

```
    this.state = {
      dateEnd: new Date(this.props.dateEnd).getTime(),
      dateStart: new Date(this.props.dateStart).getTime()
    }

... React Code....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `currentTime` and minus `dateStart` from that to find percentage.

like below to get how much percentage time completed.

```
var percentage =((new Date().getTime() - dateStart) / (dateEnd - dateStart)) * 100
```

IF you want to get to know how much time percentage left that minus 'currentTime' from `dateEnd`

```
var percentageTimeLeft =((dateEnd - new Date().getTime()) / (dateEnd - dateStart)) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I need to look into these Date functions some more I don't use them too often but when i do I always get confused.

Comment: @cosmichero2025 check out moment.js. very good date manipulation library with good inbuilt functions.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation I will!